# How do I identify if a character/symbol is a number or not?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a simple calculator using Ruby as practice. Everything is fine except **how do I identify if a character/symbol I input is a number or not using if-else statement**.

For example:

```
Enter first number: a
Error: Enter correct number
Enter first number: -
Error: Enter correct number
Enter first number: 1
Enter second number:b
Error: Enter correct number
Enter second number: 2
Choose operator (+-*/): *
The product is: 2
```

This is the code I input first:

```
print "Enter first number: "
x = gets.to_i
print "Enter second number: "
y = gets.to_i
print "Choose operator (+-*/): "
op = gets.chomp.to_s
```

I will use if-else statement to identify if the number input is a number or not

Comment: When you say "number" do you mean any numeric/quasi-numeric value or specifically an `Integer`?

Comment: How do you define "number"? Is `²` a number? What about `⑵`? Or `❷`? Is `π` a number? Is `3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196442881097566593344612847564823378678316527120190914564856692346034861045432664821339360726024914127372458700660631558817488152092096282925409171536436789259036001133053054882046652138414695194151160943305727036575959195309218611738193261179310511854807446237996274956735188575272489122793818301194912`?

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to test if the string represents an integer or float use [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) or [Kernel#Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) with the optional second argument (a hash) having the value of the key `:exception` equal to `false`.

For example,

```
Integer('-123', exception: false)
  #=> -123
Integer("0xAa", exception: false)
  #=> 170
Integer('12.3', exception: false)
  #=> nil,
Integer('12a3', exception: false)
  #=> nil
```

```
Float('123', exception: false)
  #=> 123.0 
Float("1.2e3", exception: false)
  #=> 1200.0
Float('12a3', exception: false)
  #=> nil,
Float('1.2.3', exception: false)
  #=> nil
```

Note

```
Integer("123\n", exception: false)
  #=> 123
```

shows you don't have to `chomp` before testing if the string represents an integer (similar with `Float`).

Some of the examples illustrate a limitation or complication when using a regular expression to test whether a string represents an integer or float.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new String method

```
irb(main):001:0> class String
irb(main):002:1>   def number?
irb(main):003:2>     Float(self) != nil rescue false
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1> end

irb(main):012:0> x = gets
1
=> 1
irb(main):013:0> x.number?
=> true

irb(main):009:0> x = gets
s
=> "s\n"
irb(main):010:0> x.number?
=> false
```

Comment: `#to_i` will always produce a Numeric. In the cases that you cast a non-numeric string you'll get 0. `"x".to_i.is_a?(Numeric) => true`

Comment: thanks! I edited it

Answer (score 0):

This typical way to do this would be to match it with a regexp:

```
x = gets.chomp
if x.match?(/^\d+$/)
  puts "#{x} is a number"
else
  puts "#{x} is not a number"     
end
```

This tests if the given string matches the pattern `^\d+$`, which means "start of line, one or more digit characters, then end of line". Note that this won't match characters like "," or "." - only a string of the digits 0-9. String#match? will return a boolean indicating if the string matches the given pattern or not.

Comment: This is a better use case for `match?`. Since you are only using it in a conditional a boolean is more appropriate than the otherwise truthy (`MatchData`) or falsey (`nil`). Also "123\n456" passes your current test (not sure if this matters)

Comment: Good point. I always forget that one exists!

Answer (score 0):

use this ruby method

```
.is_a?(Integer)
```

For example:

```
input = gets.chomp
input.is_a?(Integer) # => true || false
```

Comment: [`gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#gets-method) returns a string or `nil`. It will never return an integer.